# Regex for telephone number with country specific code with no spaces

Tags: regex

I would like to check if a number types take the format `+255` The numbers are always `+255*********`I want to be able to pick the contry code then 9 numbers after that **without** spaces. I simply want the country code and number without any spaces and no leading zero after the +255 as most numbers take the format. 0711223344. i I do not want to allow the user to enter the 0 right after the country code.

I am using jquery validator and would like to add a new regex lookup for the validator.
It is purely jscript.

I have

```
/^([+]255)([\d]{9})$/
```

I would like it to disable entering of 0 after the +255

Comment: Have you tried something? Please also post your efforts so far.

Comment: Which language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your expression as a base :

```
/^(+255)([1-9][\d]{8})$/
```